# How can I set up filesharing on two servers

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-access, file-sharing

I have two servers in my network, both running Windows Server 2008 R2. Server One is the firewall (with local IP `192.168.2.1`), and server Two is the web server (with local IP `192.168.2.2`) which connects to the web through server One (See image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vhpH.png). This means that server One has two network cards.

I have one shared folder on server One (folder A), and one shared folder on server Two (folder B) (regular windows sharing). I would like to be able to connect to both folders from a workstation at another location, for instance by specifying a port or something similar, but I don't how to do this.

When I connect to `\\IP-address` I get access to **folder A** (after specifying username/password).

If I go into the **Routing and remote access** configuration on server One, I can set up the following rule (See image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVFWZ.png) on port `445`. After I have set this rule, I can with `\\IP-address` access **folder B** from the remote location, but at the same time I can no longer access **folder A**. How can I set this up so that I by specifying a port or something similar from the remote location can access both folders, without having to change the settings in server One all the time (adding or removing the routing rule)?

I am not using Active Directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to make folders on two servers visible over the same IP?  Windows doesn't support this type of scenario in any way I know.  I assume you are trying to access the folder from some remote site and you might be better off setting up a PPTP or better,  L2TP or SSTP VPN on your firewall.  When you connect to the VPN, you will appear on the local LAN and be able to access both servers normally.